# How to Insert Record in combobox using Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have transaction form which contain ComboBox which contain `cityname` from `citymaster` table
I want to insert new city name from ComboBox from transaction form. I dont want to go to `CityMaster` form.

Comment: Please paste the relevant code.

Comment: Are you try `AutoCompleteMode`?